# one of threads doesn't stop sometimes

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client

I have 2 programs, one is server listening for connection and then receiving data and acknowledge them. This one is simple and I don't have question on

```
import socket, sys, time
LEN = 32
class TCPserver:
    def __init__(self):
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serverport = 11123
        server_socket.bind(("", serverport))    
        server_socket.listen(5)
        print "mimslistener waiting for client on server '%s' - port %s" % (socket.gethostname(),serverport)
        while 1:
            self.st = ""
            self.oldPktNo = -1
            self.client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
            count = -1
            while 1:
                try:
                    count += 1
                    data = self.client_socket.recv(LEN)
                    # create error on the transmission
                    if count in [2, 8, 20,30,40]:
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                    elif count in [1, 5, 11, 13,23,33,43]:
                        continue         
                    sentStr = "{:{width}s}".format(self.checkData(data), width=16)
                    self.client_socket.send(sentStr)
                except socket.error, e:
                    print e
                    break

    def checkData(self, data):
        try:
            if int(data[0:10]) <= self.oldPktNo: 
                return "ACK%010d" % self.oldPktNo
            strdata = data[10:]
            self.st += strdata
            self.oldPktNo = int(data[0:10])
            return "ACK%010d" % self.oldPktNo
        except Exception,e:
            return "AGAIN" 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TCPserver()
```

The second one is client, I implement 2 threads. One creates connection to server, then send data to server, waiting for acknowledge from server. The other try to check monitor flag every 0.5 second, if see the state is waiting for ack from server (monitor=0), it will resend the packet. (I don't want to check on sending all data so I omit that part to shorten the program.) When clicking 'cancel' which set monitor=-1, intending to force the two threads to exit loop to finish, sendPktThread wait 1 second for the monitorThread to finish first then close the connection.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Queue, threading
import socket, time, tkMessageBox
SEVERLEN = 32
LEN = SEVERLEN-10
prg = "001"
monitor = None
text ="""
[Verse 1]:You're the God of this City 
You're the King of these people 
You're the Lord of this nation You are 
[Chorus]For greater things have yet to come 
And greater things are still to be done in this City 
Greater thing have yet to come 
And greater things are still to be done in this City 
There is no one like our God There is no one like our God
"""
class TCPclient:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        Button(self.parent, text="send lines", command=self.sendPktsCmd).pack(side=TOP)
        Button(self.parent, text="Alive State", command=self.aliveStatCmd).pack(side=TOP)
        Button(self.parent, text="cancel", command=self.cancelSendCmd).pack(side=TOP)
        self.sendingStatVar = StringVar()
        Label(self.parent, textvariable=self.sendingStatVar).pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    def aliveStatCmd(self):
        print "thread0 alivestat=", self.thread0.isAlive()
        print "thread1 alivestat=", self.thread1.isAlive()

    def cancelSendCmd(self):
        global monitor
        monitor=-1

    def sendPktsCmd(self):
        global monitor
        self.data = self.split_by_len(text*3, LEN)
        self.totalPkts = len(self.data)
        self.no = 0

        self.setSendingState(self.totalPkts, 0) 
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client_socket.connect(("localhost", 11123))

        self.client_socket.send( self.createPkt(self.data[self.no], self.no) )
        monitor = 1
        receivedNo = -1
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.thread0 = ThreadedTask(self.queue, self, 0)
        self.thread0.start()
        self.thread1 = ThreadedTask(self.queue, self, 1)
        self.thread1.start()


    def monitorThread(self):
        global monitor
        if monitor == 1:
            try:
                self.client_socket.send( self.createPkt(self.data[self.no], self.no) )
            except Exception, e:
                print "error in monitorThread: ", e
                self.result = -1
                monitor = -1


    def sendPktsThread(self):
        global monitor
        try:
            data = self.client_socket.recv(16)
            print data
            if monitor!=-1: monitor = 0
            if (data[:3] == 'ACK'):
                try:
                    receivedNo = int(data[3:14])
                except: pass
                if self.no == receivedNo:
                    self.no = self.no + 1

                self.setSendingState(self.totalPkts, self.no)
            self.client_socket.send( self.createPkt(self.data[self.no], self.no) )
            if monitor!=-1: monitor = 1

        except Exception, e:
            print "error in sendPktsThread:",e
            self.result = -1
            monitor = -1

    def setSendingState(self, totalPkts, pktNo=None):
        msg = "Sending %s/%s." % (pktNo, totalPkts)
        self.sendingStatVar.set(msg)
        self.parent.update()

    def createPkt(self, st, pktNo):          
        pktNoStr = "%010d" % pktNo # 10
        return pktNoStr + st         

    def split_by_len(self, text, n):
        data = ["".join(text[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(text), n)]
        data[-1] = "{:{width}s}".format(data[-1],width=n)
        return data


class ThreadedTask(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, parent, funcalled):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.parent = parent
        self.funcalled = funcalled

    def run(self):
        global monitor
        while monitor!=-1:
            if self.funcalled == 0 : 
                print "sendPktsThread monitor=", monitor
                self.parent.sendPktsThread()
            else:
                print "monitorThread monitor=", monitor
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.parent.monitorThread()

        if self.funcalled == 0 : 
            time.sleep(1)
            self.parent.client_socket.close()
            print "Done with sendPktsThread - monitor=%s" % monitor
        else: 
            print "Done with monitorThread - monitor=%s" % monitor


root = Tk()
root.title("Test Button")
main_ui = TCPclient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However sometimes, there is only one thread finish, I don't know what the other thread doing at that time. Can anyone explain it to me and help me a solution?

(to test: run the server program first, then run client program. Click "send lines" to start sending data, then click "cancel" to stop sending data. Click "Alive State" to check which threads are still alive. For the first few "send lines" and "cancel", you can get the states of two threads False (which is what I expect. About the 3rd or 4th time, one of the threads will be True)

Comment: Have you tried setting the threads `daemon` attribute to `True` ?

Comment: @ plover: After your comment, I've tried that but it only help to finish the threads when I close the program, not when I click the cancel button

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is. That's when server lost some packet and didn't send the ACK. if the monitorThread already stopped because monitor flag = -1, program had no way to resend the packet. The sendPktsThread kept waiting to receive the ACK and would never get that. So I change the program to let the monitorThread keep resending packet until the sendPktsThread completely stop.

```
def monitorThread(self):
    global monitor
    try:
        self.client_socket.send( self.createPkt(self.data[self.no], self.no) )
    except Exception, e:
        print "error in monitorThread: ", e
        self.result = -1
        monitor = -2
```

in ThreadedTask

```
def run(self):
    global monitor
    if self.funcalled == 0:
        while monitor > -1:
            self.parent.sendPktsThread()
        print "Done with sendPktsThread - monitor=%s" % monitor
        monitor = -2
    else:
        while monitor > -2:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.parent.monitorThread()  
        print "Done with monitorThread - monitor=%s" % monitor
        self.parent.client_socket.close()
```